Algebraic simplification of nested radicals and fractions in general?
Explicit here means representable by radicals.
Let
${}^{-}$ denote the algebraic closure,
$n\in\mathbb{N}_+$,
$\mathbb{K}\in\{\mathbb{Q},\mathbb{C}\}$,
$A(x_1,...,x_n)\in\overline{\mathbb{K}(x_1,...,x_n)}$ an explicit rational or irrational $\mathbb{K}$-algebraic expression.
Can any equation
$$A(x_1,..,x_n)=0\tag{1}$$
be rearranged by applying only a finite number of explicit $\mathbb{K}$-algebraic functions so that all divisions and all negative exponents are removed?
Is there a general systematic and complete method or algorithm?
It is commonly used for solving algebraic irrational equations by transforming it into a polynomial equation. Is my assumption correct that the resulting polynomial equation is the zeroing equation of the minimal polynomial?
But here an equivalent integral rational or algebraic irrational equation over $\mathbb{K}$ is wanted. I need this for a proof of unsolvability of some kinds of equations of transcendental functions, e.g. elementary functions.
I'm familiar with elementary algebra, but the answers can also be in the language of abstract algebra.
see e.g. Moses, J.: Algebraic simplification: A guide for the perplexed. Commun. ACM 14 (1971) (8) 527-537

It's not at all clear what you are looking for. Could you give examples of the kind of rearrangements you find acceptable, and also examples of what's not ok? For example, if $n=5$, $\Bbb{K}=\Bbb{C}$ and $A$ is a root of the equation ($T$ is the variable)
$$
T^5-x_1T^4+x_2T^3-x_3T^2+x_4T-x_5=0,
$$
then $A$ is an element of the algebraic closure $\overline{\Bbb{C}(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5)}$, but we know (by Galois theory) that $A$ cannot even be written as a nested root involving elements of $\Bbb{C}(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5)$. What would it mean to rearrange $A$.

@JyrkiLahtonen I added this to my question now.
